# Add first row to header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get Data from a API (alpha_vantage) supposed in "pandas" Format. 
I create a pd.DataFrame with this Data. After this the Table / DataFrame should be insert into my MYSQL Database to make something and compare this DataFrame to another, etc ...

But the values from header are in the header AND in the first row.
When I rename the columns, the values in the Dataframe where NaN.

Have you any idea to fix this DataFrame?

```
open    high    low close   volume
date                    
2019-07-05 14:21:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2019-07-05 14:22:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2019-07-05 14:23:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2019-07-05 14:24:00 NaN NaN NaN
```

This is the DataFrame directly after the import:

```
    1. open 2. high 3. low  4. close    5. volume
date                    
2019-07-05 14:21:00 136.890 136.9300    136.87  136.9300    17242.0
2019-07-05 14:22:00 136.920 136.9200    136.90  136.9000    15627.0
2019-07-05 14:23:00 136.905 136.9149    136.89  136.9149    21360.0
2019-07-05 14:24:00 136.920 136.9400    136.90  136.9000    14474.0
2019-07-05 14:25:00 136.905 136.9400    136.90  136.9350    10476.0
```

The actual code from this job:

```
#db-connection#
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="xxx",port="xxx",user="xxx",passwd="xxx",database="traiding")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


#data#
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import csv
ts = TimeSeries(key='xxxx', output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='MSFT',interval='1min', outputsize='compact')

df_data=pd.DataFrame(data=data) #, columns=(['open','high','low','close','volume']))





#write data in db#


#mydb.commit()

print("1 record inserted, ID:", mycursor.lastrowid)

mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
print("Connection Closed")

df_data.head()
```

Comment: you didnt explain this issue properly. Can you expand on what you mean by `But the values from header are in the header AND in the first row. When I rename the columns, the values in the Dataframe where NaN`. It is really not clear what you mean.

Comment: you can insert pandas dataframe directly to database using `.to_sql`, no need to use cursor. try this: `df_data.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='tablename', if_exists='replace')` let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I need the column “date” in the header. When I try to manipulate this DataFrame, the Data where lost ?!? and set ‘NaN’.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works for me. I can easily get the `date` column and the full data in `df_data`

Comment: How can you get the "date"? This is not a column, this is only a string in the first row. that's exactly my problem, what I need to solve. --> "date" must be the first column! But i've no idea how

Comment: okay, the `date` is the index of the dataframe, you can select by calling `df_data.index`

Comment: you can do a new dataframe withough date and index and select the two columns explicitly like this: `dnew=df.reset_index()
dnew[['date','1. open']]`